# Run a spec from another spec?

Tags: ruby, rspec

I have a spec like this:

```rb
it "creates a new deal"
  # visit 'new' page
  # use capybara to fill out lots of form fields and hit submit
  # test all the values of the created Deal object
end
```

I want my next spec to test that `it "redirects to the show page for the newly created deal"`, and I'd love if it could just pick up where the last spec left off and test the `current_path`.

Is there a way to say "run this other spec and then add these expectations to it"? Rather than pasting in all the directions from the other spec.

Comment: It's probably better to make helper methods and call those from the tests

Answer (score 1):

You could also use shared examples in your specs to reuse it.

```
Rspec.shared_examples "submits a new deal" do |needed_params| 
  # visit 'new' page
  # use capybara to fill out lots of form fields and hit submit

  it "has the correct values" do 
    # test all the values of the created Deal object 
  end
end
```

And in your code, you can reuse it in a nested context like:

```
it_behaves_like "submits a new deal", "params1"
```

or include it in the current context using:

```
include_examples "submits a new deal", "params"
```

See: https://relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-core/docs/example-groups/shared-examples

Answer (score 0):

I prefer to group those behaviors in a module and include it in my features specs.

In your case, I would create a `spec/features/common.rb` module

```rb
# frozen_string_literal: true

module Features
  module Common
    def submit_new_deal
      # visit 'new' page
      # use capybara to fill out lots of form fields and hit submit
    end
end
```

and include it in `spec/rails_helper.rb` like this:

```rb
 # Include common functionality for features
 config.include Features::Common, type: :feature
```

Finally reuse it in feature specs:

```rb
it "creates a new deal"
  submit_new_deal
  # test all the values of the created Deal object
end
```

Answer (score 0):

> I want my next spec to test that it "redirects to the show page for
>   the newly created deal", and I'd love if it could just pick up where
>   the last spec left off and test the current_path.

You can use [shared contexts](https://relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-core/docs/example-groups/shared-context) to share setup steps, let blocks etc.

```
RSpec.shared_context "authenticated" do
  let(:user){ create(:user) }
  before do
    login_as(user, scope: :user)
  end
end
```

You can also use [shared examples](https://relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-core/v/3-8/docs/example-groups/shared-examples) if you need to test for the same behaviour in multiple cases.

```
RSpec.shared_examples "requires authentication" do
  before { do_request }
  it "redirects the user to the login page" do
     expect(response).to redirect_to('/login')
  end
end
```

However running the same specs just to setup the state for tests is going to be a quite slow solution. Test once and then use factories / stubs to setup the dependencies for later tests.